# ps2write rasterizes Type1C font

Tags: pdf, fonts, latex, ghostscript

While using Ghostscript's `ps2write` device with documents containing TrueType or Type1 fonts works fine, it appears that given a document with a Type1C font it produces a Type3 bitmap font.

I am wondering if this expected behaviour and what the reason is.

Here the steps to reproduce:

Create a minimal document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Compiling to PDF results in a Type1 font.

```
pdflatex document.tex
```

[image: Type 1 font]

Converting to Postscript and back to PDF results in a Type1C font.

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=ps2write -sOutputFile=document.ps -f document.pdf
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o restore1.pdf document.ps
```

[image: Type 1C font]

Repeating results in a Type3 bitmap font.

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=ps2write -sOutputFile=restore1.ps -f restore1.pdf
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o restore2.pdf restore1.ps
```

[image: Type 3 bitmap font]

Fonts used in the PDF documents.

```
$ pdffonts original.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
EVFUHE+NimbusRomNo9L-Regu            Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes      4  0
$ pdffonts restore1.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
QHWNWY+CMR10                         Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no       7  0
$ pdffonts restore2.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
[none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  yes     11  0
```

Software versions used.

```
$ gs --version
10.01.2

$ pdflatex --version | head -1
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022)
```

Comment: If you think you've found a bug, report a bug. Repeatedly converting between PostScript and PDF is **exactly** the sort of thing which will lead to a loss of quality though, you should avoid that. It is certainly not the case that a Type1C (Compact Font Format) font is rendered to a type 3 bitmap, in general, but there are conditions under which it can happen. Most likely in this case is that the repeated conversion is leading to a collision in the font encoding, so ps2write is falling back to a type 3 font.

Comment: @KenS Thanks a lot for your feedback! I originally experienced the issue with a PDF document that contained a Type1C font which I cannot share and the steps described above are merely a way to experience the same behaviour. I'm certainly not advocating that it is in any way meaningful to repeatedly convert between PostScript and PDF. I have filed a [bug](https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=707584) as you advised. Is it good practice to now delete this question or should I leave it open for a while?

Comment: Umm dunno, I guess leave it open ? If I find something then you can add an answer if it seems appropriate.

Comment: So as I said on the bug thread, I managed to confuse myself with ps2write and pdfwrite. The ps2write device does indeed render type1C fonts, because those are CFF fonts and CFF isn't supported in level 2 (The ps2write device emits level 2 PostScript, hence '2'). So actually, yes, this is expected behaviour.